# Find duplicates Value and sum a duplicates using index number Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need a little help here for excel and VBA, lets says my column like this

`No Name Rank Point
  1 Foo   1
  2 Bar   1
  3 Jhon  1
  4 Doe   1`

i need to fill a point using adds the same rank by using index of number and then divide by the number of duplicates value, `point = (1+2+3+4)/4` i need an help for using a VBA script, any of help will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You dont need VBA for thet. If your data is from A1 to C5 (with Point in Column D), lke in your example, put the following formula in D2 and pull it down:

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$5,C2,$A$2:$A$5)/COUNTIF($C$2:$C$5,C2)
```

If you need VBA, just add Application.Worksheetfunction to both formula parts.

Comment: thanks for your reply @jochen, i was a newbie for VBA, can you share a script that you suggest

Comment: Sorry, this is no free coding service. Please use the macro recorder, add the formula to the column and try to change the code correspondingly to your needs. Come back if you encounter problems.